# Create a path to excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel, extract

I'm programming in C# extracting Data from an Excel file in a WindowsForm based on search parameters. I'm stuck on how to create the path to the proper Excel File to extract the data from. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: Be more specific, what is the actual problem with creating the path? It *should* be as simple as string concatenation or using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) but we can't really answer your question without more details.

Comment: Show your current attempt at forming the path, please.

Comment: How are you creating the path?  Are you using an OpenFileDialog in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a file at an arbitrary path, you'll want to either escape the backslashes

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\your\\path\\here\\file.xlsx");
```

or use `@`

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\your\path\here\file.xlsx");
```